# Why there is an symbolic link to python3 in some npm package?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-gyp, rush

I am using `rush.js` to manage my monorepo and when I run `rush deploy` command, there is an error shows that

```
ERROR: Source path is not under /runner/_work/my-fe-repo/
/usr/bin/python3
```

I found that the error is caused by some node_modules that using node_gyp, which includes an symbolic link to python3

```
root:/opt/monorepo# find . -type l | grep python3
./common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/bigint-buffer@1.1.5/node_modules/bigint-buffer/build/node_gyp_bins/python3
```

I want to know why there is an symbolic link to python3. I also want to know what is the best solution for the `rush deploy` error